# How and where to add a Devise view helper method current_user boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is the method I would like to access in my views:

```
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

I essentially need to check that the current user can not friend and unfriend themselves in the view.

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <% if current_user.friendly?(@user)
    <%= render 'unfriend' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'friend' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The current_user helper method is already provided by Devise.
How and where do I add this method in my Rails project?

Thanks for your help

Comment: add to your application_helper.rb file

Comment: I thought I was going crazy because I tried to add it to the application_helper.rb first. It didn't work. I tried again after your comment and success. Thanks @JesseWolgamott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake initially in the application_helper.rb file.

I used an instance variable `current_user?(@user)` instead of the local variable `current_user?(user)`.

If I was not using  Devise I would have put the helper method in the sessions helper. So i figured it would work in the appication helper but was not positive.

Thanks @JesseWolgamott

Answer (score 7):

To use application helper method in devise views.
Place your class_eval code at the bottom of  Devise initializer, Just after the Devise.setup block.

## config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ... existing Devise configuration, no modification necessary to include helper(s) ...
end
```

**EDIT:**

```
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
  helper :application # include "ApplicationHelper", adjust to suit your needs
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could simple add the comparison on the view like this:

```
<% if current_user != @user %>
  <% if current_user.friendly?(@user)
    <%= render 'unfriend' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'friend' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Anyway if you still want to use the method you could create a method in User.rb

```
def equal_user?(another_user)
  another_user == self
end
```

and in the view

```
<% if @user.equal_user?(current_user) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm using the Devise gem for authentication. My method worked after I tried the application_helper.rb again.